# Microsoft Dynamics 365 authentication approach

Tags: c#, authentication, dynamics-365

I have inherited some code which acts as middleware between our application and MS Dynamics 365.

It currently uses client secret based authentication, however the client secret is stored within a web.config, meaning that anyone who gets the appropriate URL to our app has access to the MS Dynamics org, which is bad...

I have updated the code to use a Certificate instead of a client secret, which makes management/housekeeping easier, but again if anyone gets the url, they have access to the org...

The middleware app code is all C# and uses the Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling namespace (CrmServiceClient) for establishing a connection to MS Dynamics 365.

The application works well, but is just insecure.

Our application is embedded within MS Dynamics as a popup page launched from a Web Resouce (some JavaScript with a window.open) and users have to be logged into MS Dynamics to be able to access this Web Resource.

In Salesforce.com, we use the SessionID to pass to the middleware to establish an API connection, but MS Dynamics doesnt seem to have anything like this available.

The call chain is basically:

MS Dynamics > Embedded page

Embedded Page > middleware app - establishes a MS Dynamics connection using clientid/secret or certificate stored within the Azure App service or Key Vault

Middleware app > our app

Our app > middleware app (to load CRM data) this is really where the security flaw is, if a nefarious user has the url to our app at this point, they effectively have access to MS Dynamics data with no authentication challenge (as the MSD connection is established using clientid/secret stored within the web.config or a certificate, which is stored on the web app)

I dont want to introduce a login screen to our app as it will break the immersion and people will hate it.

Can someone please suggest a better appproach for me?

Comment: I typical client will have GUEST privileges (Role) which should limit the access.  Using a network authentication will only allow machines that are trusted to get more access.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: thanks, but this wont work, the nature of the middleware means all users need access to all pages. I believe there is something I am missing with the pattern/architecture of the code talking to MS Dynamics 365.

Comment: Either you use GUEST or put all users into a Group.  If you are in a corporate network (Group Policy) the users should all be part of an existing group.

Comment: this is for a commercial product, not an internal one so I can't control things like youre suggesting

Comment: You must!!! When a commercial product is deployed you have to give installation instructions which needs to include security requirements.

Comment: it isnt installed anywhere on a clients premisis.. it is fully hosted by us, in Azure.

Comment: What credentials do you plan to use?  Is you server inside the clients firewall?  Do you plan on using certificates?

Comment: i am already using certificate based authentication. No its not within their firewall, its hosted within our Azure environment. We install a Microsoft Dynamics solution to client orgs which contains a Web Resource which redirects to our application in Azure

Comment: Not sure why you consider the connection not secure if you are using a certificate.  You are using a HTTPS connection  The clients will have low privilege of GUEST so they can only access what the server application allows.  What credentials is being use for the connection between the server and the database?  What I think is not secure is the server application to the database, not the client to server.

Comment: sorry, but youre just totally missing the point.
The App Service has the certificate
The App Service is publicly available
There is no problem between the app service and the database. 
The problem is the security between the App Service and Microsoft Dynamics, given the app service is publicly available and also contains the certificate, all a nefarious user needs to do is capture the URL for the app service from a valid user's browser and they will be able to access MSD data with no authentication

Comment: A certificate (contains a private key) encrypts the data and does not get transferred with the message.  The certificate is only on the client and server.  The certificate is stored in the user temp folder on his machine.  So for somebody to hack their way into your data then would need to get through the firewall and then log into a machine with a user credentials to get access to the certificate.

Comment: Very strange question - if your goal is to give users anonymous access to the data why you are concerned that users get anonymous access to the data?  Maybe you intent to give users access to some data and not all... or something like that... [Edit] or new question after you figure out exactly what you want can help.